# I can't write to a /etc/resolvconf.conf as root anymore?

Tags: shell, permissions, filesystems

I edited /etc/resolvconf.conf a few weeks ago to add this line:

```
name_servers="1.0.0.1 2606:4700:4700::1111,2606:4700:4700::1001"
```

Today, I went back to edit it again, and `sudo vim /etc/resolvconf.conf` opens the file read-only and overriding with `w!` fails. I tried `su`, and `sudo sh -c "vim /etc/resolvconf.conf"`, and nothing's working.

```
ls -l /etc/resolvconf.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 320 Jan  4 00:05 /etc/resolvconf.conf
```

What's happening here? How is this possible?

Comment: Maybe your whole filesystem is mounted read-only?

Comment: Is the root partition mounted read-only?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hope the file is set with the immutable flag

To check :

```
lsattr /etc/resolvconf.conf

----i---------- /etc/resolvconf.conf
```

To remove immutable flag

```
chattr -i /etc/resolvconf.conf
```